# Detect if gaps in numeric sequences are at random or contiguous

Tags: r, vector, random, gaps-and-islands

I have many vectors of numeric data, some of them containing gaps. I must detect if those gaps are contiguous or distributed more or less at random within each vector. Something like that exemplified here:

```
# Let's create a couple of data vectors
x <- runif(1000)
y <- runif(1000)

# Let's add some NAs at random to x
x[sample(c(1:1000), 100, replace = F)] <- NA
# Let's add some continuous NAs to y
y[c(251:350)] <- NA

# And get the respective summaries
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
0.00294 0.24446 0.51441 0.50535 0.76200 0.99850     100 
summary(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
0.00325 0.22178 0.47765 0.48207 0.73380 0.99969     100
```

That is, both x and y have the same amount of gaps, but in x these are distributed at random along the vector, while in y they are aggregated.
I must detect this, any idea?

Comment: This is really a stats question, how to detect if a subset is random or not.  I suggest moving it to stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Turn it into a tibble, then Look at the standard deviation of the line-numbers of the NA's.

```
library(tidyverse)
myt <- tibble(X = x, Y = y) %>%  
  rowid_to_column("LINE") 

myt %>% 
  filter(is.na(X)) %>% 
  pull(LINE) %>% 
  sd()
# [1] 300.2694
myt %>% 
  filter(is.na(Y)) %>% 
  pull(LINE) %>% 
  sd()
# [1] 29.01149
```

Answer (score 1):

The definition of contiguous or distributed is not really clear in the post.

Here is a function which returns `TRUE` if there is at least one series of `NA` values greater than length of `n`.

```
is_contiguous <- function(vec, n) with(rle(is.na(vec)), any(lengths[values] > n))

is_contiguous(x, 30)
#[1] FALSE

is_contiguous(y, 30)
#[1] TRUE
```